# Converting docx to csv using python-docx: issue with merged cells

Tags: python, csv, docx, python-docx

I have a .docx file (attached screenshot) with a table. I need to convert it into a .csv table. I am using python-docx for this with the code below.

My code is below. Everything works fine except the last column (G) which is a merged cell. My code ignores G1 and only reports column G2 (screenshot attached). How can I edit the code so that the .csv file has both G1 and G2 columns?

Thanks!

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

files = glob.glob('*.docx')

for name in glob.glob('*.docx'):
    document = Document(name)
    #document = Document('f.docx')
    table = document.tables[0]
    
    data = []
    
    keys = None
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
    
        if i == 0:
            keys = tuple(text)
            continue
        row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
        data.append(row_data)
        #data
        #print (data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(os.path.splitext(name)[0])
    df.to_csv(os.path.splitext(name)[0]+'.csv')
```

[image: DOCX FILE]

[image: CSV OUTPUT]

Comment: What happens if you move A-F down one row and then get rid of the top row? I expect the problem is related to the G cell in the first row being merged.